# Orthonormalizing a compact set, is it compact?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $S$ be an infinite enumerable subset of $\ell^2$ over $\mathbb{C}$ such that it is linearly independent and compact.

$T$ is obtained by orthonormalizing S

I would like to know if $T$ is compact.

Thanks.

Comment: Is infinite numerable supposed to mean countably infinite?

Comment: Hint: $(e_n / n)_{n\in mathbb N}$

Comment: @user251257 i mean countably infinite

Comment: ok @user251257 now i think to understand your hint, so it's not compact

Comment: is the set in the hint compact? What happens if you ortho**normalize** it?

Comment: @user251257 i thanks, i understood your hint, i miswrite my previous comment, now i edited

Comment: In Hillbert space any infinite orthonormal set is non-compact.  So not only $T$ can sometimes be non-compact (as @user251257 said), but it must always be non-compact.

Comment: thanks @GEdgar for your comment